# Haskell IO String -> List

Tags: haskell, io

Hey guys, I need some help, how can I sum a list from a file using the sum builtin function?

example:
text.txt contains [1,2,3,4]

and i want to get this list from the file and sum these numbers with the sum builtin. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: See also this FAQ in the [haskell+io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+io) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
main = do
    contents <- readFile "text.txt"
    print . sum . read $ contents
```

This uses some standard functions from the Prelude:

- `readFile :: FilePath -> IO String` reads the file into a string.
- `read :: Read a => String -> a` converts from a `String` to any type in the `Read` typeclass. You might have to add a type annotation if the compiler couldn't figure out which type you wanted. In this case the compiler can figure it out since we used `sum` on the result, so it infers that `a` must be `[Integer]`. (It actually infers `Num a => [a]`, but this defaults to `[Integer]` due to type defaulting).

  `read` expects the same format generated by `show` on the same type.

Note that I had to use do-notation to extract the `String` from `IO String` in order to apply `read` to it.

Comment: Technically the compiler guesses which type you wanted (by using a default), since `sum` can operate on multiple numeric types.

Answer (score 3):

So, you won't be able to actually get a value `:: [Int]`, because that would be unsafe. But we can get you to `IO [Int]`, and then pass that through `>>=` into `print`:

```
main = (sum . read) `fmap` readFile "myFile" >>= print
```

If you're using `Control.Applicative`, you can make it even prettier:

```
main = sum . read <$> readFile "myFile" >>= print
```

Voilà! As you can see, this way is much more succinct than using `do`-notation. `do`-notation is awesome for getting rid of nested lambdas, but in a lot of cases, it's really not necessary.

**Edit:** *@augustss* suggests the following superior alternative:

```
main = print . sum . read =<< readFile "myFile"
```

This is awesome, in that it's simpler, and doesn't depend on `Control.Applicative`; even more importantly, it doesn't have to read be read "inside-out", as *@hammar* points out.

Comment: @augustss Wow, that's way better! Thanks.

Comment: It also reads better, from right to left, whereas you have to read the applicative one "inside out".

Answer (score 2):

If the list is always in this kind of format, you want to use the `read` function. This function *deserializes* data, i.e. turns a string into a program data type. For example,

```
Prelude> read "[1, 2, 3, 4]" :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Now, you can combine this with file IO, but you'll need to read up on Monads if you're not familiar. Some good resources are [ http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad ] and Wikipedia. Essentially, each monad will represent a step in a sequential execution -- which is necessary since IO modifies the environment, hence its execution order must be determined.

The code I came up with for reading and then summing is:

```
main = do
    fc <- readFile "file1"
    parsed <- return (read fc :: [Int])
    putStrLn (printf "sum: %d" (sum parsed))
```

Comment: Thanks, though it's not nice it doesn't understand space delimited numbers without "[" chars around it.

Comment: @Alehar if you don't have braces, you can just try the `words` function, the strip off trailing commas. If you need something more advanced, you might try a Parsec parser.